# How do Async Javascript Programs Interact

Tags: javascript

Back in the early days of web development, I picked up a bit of folk wisdom that, for code like this

```
<script src=".../program1.js"></script>
<script src=".../program2.js"></script>
```

the browser would pause, load the javascript, compile it, execute it, move on to the next `script` tag, and repeat.  In this way, the browser would work its way through all the javascript on a page and treat it as one linear program.

However, in the brave new modern javascript world, we have asynchronous loading via the `async` attribute

```
<script src=".../program1.js" async></script>
<script src=".../program2.js" async></script>
```

It's my understanding that this is a *good thing* because now the browser does not need to pause, download the script, and execute it. Instead it starts downloading the script, but will continue to parse the DOM.  i.e. the web page no longer blocks while waiting for javascript to download. (if this is not true I'd appreciate the correction).

However, what's less clear (and harder to test) is how these two programs interact.  They appear to run in the same shared space (i.e. javascript is still, from a userland perspective, single threaded with two (global, function) scopes).  However, what order they execute in seems ill-defined in the documentation I've read.

I've read through the MDN article on [Concurrency model and Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).  While interesting and useful, it doesn't quite answer my question.  From what I gather, when the browser loads `program1.js` or `program2.js`, javascript will add a message to the event queue, and that message will be processed as the javascript engine runs through the event loop.

What's missing for me is -- what does that message say?  Is it a single message for each program that says "compile and execute all this javascript code"?  Or does each program create multiple messages -- in my mind that might look something like

- Message 1: Extract all the functions from this program and compile them
- Message 2: Extract all statements and expressions in the global scope from this program
- Message 3-n: Add each statement and expression as an individual queue message for later processing.

And what happens when the browser is in the middle of processing `program1.js`, but finishes downloading `program2.js`?  Is it possible that execution of statements from each program will be interleaved?

I realize that, as a client developer, the best practice here is to not rely on global scope and write each program and function so it doesn't matter how it's called, and doesn't block other people's code.  However, I spend a lot of time dealing with other people's code, some of which isn't well behaved. I'd like to understand what's going on behind the scenes, or if this is behavior that's undefined and, engine independent, and won't line up between implementations.

Comment: From the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-initializehostdefinedrealm): *"In an implementation dependent manner, obtain the ECMAScript source texts (see clause 10) and any associated host-defined values for zero or more ECMAScript scripts and/or ECMAScript modules. For each such sourceText and hostDefined,
If sourceText is the source code of a script, then
Perform EnqueueJob("ScriptJobs", ScriptEvaluationJob, « sourceText, hostDefined »). [...]"*

Comment: Thank you Felix!  +1 for useful information -- however, as I'm not neck deep in implementing javascript engines, it's not 100% clear how the above spec translates into actual javascript behavior.  i.e. in lazily reading your helpful comment, I'm left wondering if maybe a ScriptEvaluationJob ends up enqueuing additional messages for each loaded javascript file.

Comment: If you search for `EnqueueJob` in the spec you will see that the only other cases where `EnqueueJob` is called is in the context of promises. So the answer to your question would be: yes, more jobs could be enqueued. However, I have to admit that it's not clear to me either how a *browser's* [event loop](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/webappapis.html#event-loop) relates to this.

Answer (score 7):

There are two articles illustrate the "async" and "defer" properties in a practical sense (I'm green on the browser internals):

From 2014 with excellent + simple graphics:
http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html

From 2016 why async might be an anti-pattern:
http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2016/prefer-defer-over-async/

### Async

To your question, what "async" instructs the browser to do is:

1. Start downloading this resource as early as possible.
2. Move on and feel free to download other resources in parallel.
3. But as soon as my download completes, stop rendering and begin executing me as early as possible.

Effectively "async" can still block rendering and subsequent execution, but it allows the parser to continue working right up until execution can begin.

Multiple async scripts have no guarantee what order they will execute in. Depends how quickly the load. That lets AMD-systems like RequireJS define dependencies and callbacks to load resources async but queue their execution until the "global" environment contains all the prerequisites and the execution order can be negotiated (by rune magic) hopefully.

### Defer

Defer behaves like this:

1. Start downloading this resource as early as possible.
2. Move on and feel free to download other resources in parallel.
3. But as soon as my download completes, do nothing until the parser is done.
4. Now execute all the scripts in the order they were discovered.

On one hand, "defer" is faster because it can never block the parser or rendering. But "defer" can be slower because it must wait to execute until the pipeline is clear.

That sounds like "async" is always better, but if you load 2 MB of JS on weak-CPU phone with a fast connection you may end up waiting 10s for execution before the parser is allowed to finish rendering. Using "defer" would prevent that at the expense your interaction layer being delayed.

The distinction is fuzzier if you're talking client/server or client-side apps. It may be more beneficial to use defer in a backend heavy app like Magento where rendering is handled server-side.

In a fully client-side app you probably get zero content until the JS monolith is loaded, so "defer" doesn't really do anything for you, but then neither does "async" if your whole app is a massive JS bundle and there's nothing to do in parallel.

Comment: And advance apologies for not addressing "concurrency and the event loop". I know you were looking for the chemical engineer perspective on friction modifiers, and I gave the mechanic perspective on using synthetic or conventional oil (they're all better than using water for oil).

Comment: Both perspectives are useful @Brendan -- I'm actually looking for a unified string theory that explains it top to bottom :)

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible that execution of statements from each program will be interleaved?

No, absolutely not. JS is still single-threaded, and one program runs after the other (although which of them comes first might be unknown).

> What does that event loop message say?

The message is a [*ScriptEvaluationJob*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-scriptevaluationjob). Assuming parsing of the script is successful, it will instantiate all declarations and evaluate the script body, all in one run.